# Java EE multi tiered application with Swing client

Tags: java, hibernate, servlets, jakarta-ee, ejb

I have to develop enterprise level application using Java technologies. I decided to develop client side environment with swing and server side related things using Java EE components. My planned way could be described as following

First swing client makes request to application server. And application server has business logic and it has ability to decide which way should transfer my requests. Database server has my DBs.

these technologies I willing to use.

- swing for client side
- servlet for HTTP request handling in application server
- EJB for handling business logic in application server
- Hibernate to access my DBs form EJB.

Could you tell me above architecture is compatible with JEE enterprise level system architecture?

Comment: What do you mean "Will I able to use spring those app server programing?". Are you talking about the Spring framework?

Comment: sorry. omit that part. i'll remove it

Comment: think without that. :)

Comment: It is cpmpatible. Though why Swing? What about JavaFX, Eclipse RCP? :)

Comment: Do JavaFX use in industry?? I heard JavaFX has rejected from industry and industry doesn't use it. that's why I planned to use swing.

Comment: @Top25 You say you *have to* develop this. Is it a school project?

Comment: nope this is professional project. I'm going to create open source software platform to do some particular task

Answer (score 0):

Swing <==>Socket<==>JEE (Application) REST based <==>Hiberate (DAO)
Yes its good but.
But if your application is going to be used by different end user devices then you need to think different way of client side.
Using JNLP you can deliver your SWING client items to your end users that will give you better upgradation and later customization also possible without any intimation to your clients.

This is my points only.